# C++ Submatrix from a Multidimensional Vector/Matrix

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, matrix, submatrix

In MSVS C++ I have a multidimensional vector (matrix). I am not using arrays.

For example:

```
vector< vector<float> > image(1056, vector<float>(366));
```

After data is included in the vector from another source how is it possible to create a sub matrix from this matrix, given an pixel co-ordinate and the number of columns and rows needed?

For example, I have:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
```

I want:

```
6  7
10 11
```

Seems basic but I am new to this concept. There are examples but they use arrays and I was unable to change the samples around for my own need.

Comment: Look at Boost.uBlas if you have a lot of this type of thing to do and perf is not so critical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do it. You should create new two-dimensional array of desired size and copy pieces of data to it.

You may want to access matrix through some view, which would be proxy class, mapping view indices, to underlaying data indices